# How do i change object properties to have double quotes?

Tags: javascript

How do I change an object to have double quotes as a property in JavaScript?

Example:
{ C: 10, H: 16, N: 5, O: 13, P: 3 }​​​​ => ​​​​​​​​​​{ "C": 10, "H": 16, "N": 5, "O": 13, "P": 3 }

Comment: a) that's not an array, but an object. b) what does it matter to you? both are the same within the code.

Comment: where do you need double quotes?

Comment: I have now edited the question so it's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stringify it.

```js
var obj = { C: 10, H: 16, N: 5, O: 13, P: 3 },
    json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    
    console.log(json);
```

Comment: This will produce `'​​​​​​​​​​{ "C": 10, "H": 16, "N": 5, "O": 13, "P": 3 }'`

Comment: @TPOT94 Missed parsing. Fixed.

Comment: it does not really change the internal representation of the object, by stringify and parsing.

Comment: @NinaScholz Do you have any other solution then?

Comment: i don't see actually an problem without further information about the purpose of the given object.

Comment: What Kind user is showing me is what I wanted to get. Thanks Kind user

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what Niputi expected: double quotes as a property.

```js
let input = {C: 10, H: 16, N: 5, O: 13, P: 3};
let output = {};

for (let key in input) {
    output['"' + key + '"'] = input[key];
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, the original object's properties remain unchanged in the preceding two solutions in which each creates a new object.  The OP indicated a desire to alter the original object.  In that case, either of the preceding solutions is fine in conjunction with deleting the unquoted properties, too.  One way to accomplish this feat in JavaScript is as follows:

```
var o = {
   C: 10,
   H: 16,
   N: 5,
   O: 13,
   P: 3
};

for (let k in o) {
   o["\"" + k + "\""] = o[k];
   delete o[k];
 }

 // the changed object
 for (let p in o) {
   console.log(p, o[p]);
 }
```

See live [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRWrwy)